# Errors on importing sql file in phpMyadmin

Tags: sql, xampp, mariadb

Here is a snapshot of the errors.
I am using xampp on ubuntu to run the mysql server. The error says to check the manual of MariaDB server , so does xampp support that or is there something wrong with the SQL query? . This SQL file was provided in a github project [Github project link](https://github.com/dhanesh939/College-Management-System) . If what I am doing to import this SQL file to create the database is totally wrong, please suggest the correct way to do it.

[image]

A snippet of the SQL file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWPWgBq8xHV-zfPHAKngFQI66JwVHv71/view?usp=sharing  This is the SQL file

[image: A snippet of the SQL file]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the SQL file as text, not as screenshot. Some might want to run it, to find the problem. A version information of your MySQL/MariaDB (which one is it actually?) might also be helpful.

Comment: Yes , I provided the link for the SQL file